# Incremental load in greenplum

Tags: etl, greenplum

I have external and internal tables in greenplum. External table is pointing in hdfs a  csv file. This csv file in Hdfs getting load with full data of a table every hour. 
What is best way to load data incrementally in internal table of the greenplum.

Comment: It depends on the SLA and how long it takes to load the entire table using gphdfs.  truncate and insert might be the best way.  insert into target_table select * from external_table where column > 'value' might be the best way.  Or you might need to dynamically create an external table for every load.

Comment: I have checked using gphdfs able to load entire data in the external table is very fast. However instead of truncate entire table wants to go for incremental load in Greenplum.

Comment: I think you just answered your own question then.

Comment: Thanks, I am able to load data incrementally in Greenplum

Answer (score 0):

create dimension table in greenplum where it store last of the till where it loaded previously like timestamp or any datapoint.

use above dimension table , you can an UDF return in such a way that evry one hour whenever a new file arrives ,  it will loaded to stage/extrenal table  and then with last loaded parameters from  dimension table the , it will  pick only relevant/new  records  to process further.

Thanks,
shobha